# Form not listed in Windows Service Project Start up objects in VS.net 2008

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a windows service in VS.net 2008. Just to test the application before I install the service, I have a form (Form1.cs).
Now when I want to make this project as startup project and form1 as startup object,
I don't see the form one in the start up object list.
I just see the namespace of the Program.cs and not set

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you don't have a

```
static void Main()
```

method in Form1.cs. (The method could return `int` and/or take a `string[]` parameter, and it doesn't have to be private.) That's what makes VS consider a class to be a potential entry point.

To be honest, it's be pretty odd IMO to have a form in the same project as a service. Why not have a separate project for it which would work in the normal way? Having multiple entry points is fine, but if one of them starts a service and the other opens a form instead, that's a little strange.